# How to check current user membership from item control template (sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

Ive made a item control template for SharePoint online. It's working like a charm and all that, however ive been asked to hide a buttom depending on current users membership.

So my question is. How do one get membership information on current user in a control template in SharePoint online ?

Answer (score 0):

The following post explains how to check the user's permissions to a certain securable object, such as a list item.

http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/checking-user-permissions-from-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/

Possibly you can use that information to verify whether the user (and group to which he/she belongs) has access to the resource related to the action button. This is the standard way really to check for permissions in SharePoint and preferred over checking if a user is or isn't in a group (as the group may have it's permissions changed in the future).

Comment: So... REST is the way to go? To be hornest i was thinking myself it could be done using the client model?

Comment: What would be the issue with using the REST endpoints?